# Submitting an image alongside a form with one button

Tags: php, html, forms, submit

I have a regular form which submits to my database but I want to include a file upload in the form, so as to receive the form input in the expected table using PHP post and also receive the uploaded image.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<input type="file">` to include a file upload in the form.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this to send Files as well as other inputs to the processing page where you can access files and post variables.

```
<form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" name="txtbox">
<br />
<input type="file" name="filebox">
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

When this is submitted you can access the data from $_FILES and $_POST

Answer (score -1):

> There are various input types in HTML just as the below:

```
<input type="button">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="color">
<input type="date">
<input type="datetime-local">
<input type="email">
<input type="file">
<input type="hidden">
<input type="image">
<input type="month">
<input type="number">
<input type="password">
<input type="radio">
<input type="range">
<input type="reset">
<input type="search">
<input type="submit">
<input type="tel">
<input type="text">
<input type="time">
<input type="url">
<input type="week">
```

> Each of the above inputs demand different conditions and formats to be satisfied.

For your query the answer is either:

```
<input type="file">
```

> For webpages that require inputs in a file format. Or,

```
<input type="image">
```

> For webpages requiring input in an image format.

**For further details view the below link for help:**

> https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp